# Is it beneficial to inline all JavaScript when deploying a website

Tags: javascript, html, deployment

In our HTML page, we have a list of  tags to load in many (small) JavaScript source files.

For deployment we plan to concatenate the individual JavaScript files into one bundle which will be included in the HTML page, to save on 'expensive' HTTP requests.

But would it be even more beneficial, to just write all the JavaScript directly into the HTML file, in an in-line Javascript  tag?

Comment: Why don't you use an external javascript file?

Comment: thanks for all the correct answers - it's quite obvious now I think about it. I could have chosen one of many answers as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way would be to concatenate them but *don't* put them directly into you html-file. that way the js-file can be cached independently from the (probably) changing html-source.

Answer (score 4):

If the JavaScript code changes on every request ("tags"?), then yes, it's beneficial.

Otherwise: No, because the browser will not be able to cache the JS files.

Answer (score 2):

A file is better than writing the whole stuff into the HTML, as you can cache the javascript file coming from your server, but unless you cache all .html files, you won't get this benefit (i.e. browsers have to keep redownloading all the inline scripts inside your html files)

Answer (score 2):

> But would it be even more beneficial, to just write all the JavaScript directly into the HTML file, in an in-line Javascript tag?

No! You would increase the size of every request and destroy cacheability. One big (but external) JS file is the way to go.

Make sure the JS file is emitting the proper caching headers, and it will be loaded only once per client. Unless your JS is exceedingly small (and your description doesn't sound so), that's pretty much the optimum.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you compile all your javascript into one file and load it with one `<script>` tag. Yes, HTTP requests take some time, and browsers limit number of concurrent requests (to one domain).

I wouldn't put all javascript in the HTML, because this is mixing logic and representation, prevents caching (of javascript), etc. Avoid this.

This is the general rule I follow: separate content that changes often from content that changes rarely. This way static content will be cached efficiently. And you can optimize "fluid" content (gzip, minify, etc.) so that it takes less time to load.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean 'embed inside a `<script>` block' rather than in 'on*' attributes inside the HTML elements. If that's not the case, the answer is a definite no - 'on*' attributes are harder to maintain, and typically bad for accessibility.

Normally the answer is no, because although the user's first request will be more expensive if it has to get external resources, those resources will be cached so future requests will be cheaper. If you embed everything, the user has to load them every time they load the page.

So it depends on a few things, the most important of which are probably:

- Are users browsing multiple pages? Will they return? If the answer to both questions is 'no', then there is no benefit from caching, so embedded JavaScript can be quicker.
- Is the JavaScript static? If it's dynamic - as in, changes on every page load, then again, caching is irrelevant. You could probably improve your JavaScript architecture to separate the static bits from the dynamic.

You can mix the JavaScript so that static JavaScript is linked, while dynamic or page-specific JavaScript is embedded. This is especially useful with libraries - it may already be cached in the client from another site, but if not, you're still loading from a CDN like Google, so it's very quick.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought so.

I always just include files and try to keep my base html looking as clean as possible.

Comment: It's just as part of the build/deployment stage that we are minimizing and bundling the JavaScript - in development we always work with a clean base html page (as you describe it.)

Answer (score 0):

Die hards will say don't do it, separate content from styles and scripting, and I agree.  But if its not a lot of JS, you may as well save on any additional HTTP requests.  Yes, the browser won't cache it, but that's because it won't need to.  And on an SEO basis, Page ranking is improved with faster page load, determined possibly on first visit, not after a cache.